# How do I return the employees with salary greater than 15000?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `EMP` and `Salary`, where on `EMP` table I have the following fields:

```
id, emp_name,designation
```

And on the `Salary` table I have the following fields:

```
id, emp_id, salary
```

How can I get the name of employee whose salary is greater than 15000?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` and `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT emp_name 
  FROM EMP 
  JOIN Salary
    ON EMP.id = Salary.emp_id
 WHERE salary > 15000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner query, like this:

```
SELECT emp_name
FROM   emp
WHERE  id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM salary WHERE salary > 15000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework? I will just give you the necessary hints rather than a complete statement:

The reason for salary being a table on its own is that an employee can have more than one salary. (Otherwise salary would just be a field in emp table).

So first join emp and salary to get all salaries for all employees. Then group by employees to get the sum of the salaries for each employee. Then at last filter your results to salaries over 15000. Do you know already how to filter group results?

There is more than one way to write a correct statement. I am sure you will find one using the hints given. Good luck!